# Table inside a jQuery UI tab increases in size

Tags: jquery-ui-tabs

As the title says, after putting a form (enclosing a table) inside a tab, the table size increases in height due to the input elements having their font family (and size?) changed.

Has anyone else experienced this problem and if so how can be it overcome?  I am thinking that perhaps each input element can have a class attached to it and setting font family and size that way.  However I don't know if this is correct and if there is a much simpler solution.

Any advice on this would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with CSS. Include this in a CSS file loaded after the jQuery UI css.

```
.ui-tabs-panel table
{
    font-size: 80%;
}
```

Note that you might have to adjust the selector to make it more specific (for example, use a specific table id).